# PHP XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I'm really newby in php and I want to make an XMLHttpRequest in my php page and don't know who can I do it.

This is the Chrome info, as you can see the header is XMLHttpRequest :
[Chrome Request Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg39y.png)

This is the response data (a table):
[Chrome XHR response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o08qk.png)

How can I made this request in my php page??

PD - sorry for my poor english)

Comment: are you sure you want to use PHP for making that request , as I will use ajax for the same. In case you want to check an example, have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_xml.asp

Comment: @Satya Thanks, don't know really well what have to use :S  I have a php page and I only want to get this table that you can see at the 2nd link from a website who is not mine and don't know how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl if you wanna do an XMLHttpRequest using PHP. By putting the right header you will make look like you're doing a XMLHttpRequest

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return result as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Host" = > "someloginserver.com",
    "User-Agent" = > "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1",
    "Accept" = > "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Language" = > "en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding" = > "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Charset" = > "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
    "Keep-Alive" = > "115",
    "Connection" = > "keep-alive",
    "X-Requested-With" = > "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Referer" = > "http://remote/"
));
// Execute curl
$result = curl_exec($ch); // The output will be stored $result
// Check Error
if ($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
} else {
    echo "<h2>Request Completed</h2>";
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: works for me!!!! but when I call curl_exec the result is shown in my webpage and I only want the table (XHR data) in plaintext to extract some data, is there any way?

Comment: @dina I just edited my answer you need to add the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER options and set it to true. Then you'll have the result in plaintext inside the $result variable. From that you'll be able to do any extraction work

Answer (score 1):

Even if I don't know any details, mostly **SimpleXML** can help :)

For this `feed.xml`-Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items>
    <title>Cities</titel>
    <item>
        <cityname>Genf</cityname>
    </item>
    <item>
        <cityname>Köln</cityname>
    </item>
</items>
```

Try:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
?>
```